# Force all Kotlin Sealed classes to have a standard entry?

Tags: kotlin, sealed-class

I am investigating Kotlin Sealed Classes.

I wish to force all my Sealed classes to have a standard value of NO_OP.

for example:-

*Sealed Class 1*

```
sealed class Operation {
    object NO_OP: Operation()
    class Add(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Substract(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Multiply(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Divide(val value: Int) : Operation()
}
```

*Sealed Class 2*

```
sealed class ScreenState {
    object NO_OP: ScreenState()
    class Error : ScreenState()
    class Loading : ScreenState()
    data class Data(val someData: SomeData) : ScreenState()
}
```

Is there any approach I can take that will force all sealed classes in separate files to
always specify the NO_OP value?

Answer (score 2):

If you want force override it as a field for a **certain** sealed class:

```
sealed class ScreenState {
    abstract val NO_OP: ScreenState

    class Error : ScreenState() {
       override val NO_OP: ScreenState
          get() = TODO("Your implementation")
    }
}
```

If you need something like an **interface**:

```
sealed class ScreenState : NoOp<ScreenState> {
    override val NO_OP: ScreenState = Error()

    class Error : ScreenState()
}

interface NoOp<T> {
   val NO_OP: T
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That seems not possible at the moment in the language.
However, we can move the `NO_OP` out from the sealed hierarchies and use `Coproduct` from the Arrow Library to define an ad-hoc sealed hierarchy:

```
import arrow.generic.coproduct2.Coproduct2

sealed class Operation {
    class Add(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Substract(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Multiply(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Divide(val value: Int) : Operation()
}

object NO_OP

typealias Operations = Coproduct2<NO_OP, Operation>
```

Or we can fix one of the type parameters in `Coproduct`, and have:

```
typealias SomeThingWithNoOp<T> = Coproduct<NO_OP, T>
```

However, this is not ideal as it makes the hierarchy nested. With the top-level being `Coproduct`, and the nested level being the customized hierarchy. 
This may be addressed with Arrow-Meta's union type plugin in the near future.

---

Another way of seeing the problem is treating `NO_OP` as the sentinel value. So we may encode `NO_OP` as null or `None`(From Arrow Option):

```
sealed class Operation {
    class Add(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Substract(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Multiply(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Divide(val value: Int) : Operation()
}

typealias Operations = Operation?
```

```
import arrow.core.Option

sealed class Operation {
    class Add(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Substract(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Multiply(val value: Int) : Operation()
    class Divide(val value: Int) : Operation()
}

typealias Operations = Option<Operation>
```

From my experience, encoding it as nullable may be easier to use, as Kotlin has the nullable type support built-in. While encoding it as `Option`, `Coproduct` or defining `NO_OP` in each of the sealed hierarchies would make it more obvious(especially by using `Coproduct` or `NO_OP` in the sealed hierarchy).

---

Ref:

- Coproduct: https://0-9-0.arrow-kt.io/docs/generic/coproduct/
- Option: https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core-data/arrow.core/-option/